# Kafka Consumer distribution not working as expected

Tags: apache-kafka, partitioning, consumer, kafka-topic

I have Three topics each having three partitions on a cluster of kafka.

now, there are total 9 partitions. and when i create 9 consumers... the 6 are being idle. only three consumers are being used.

the expectation is: each consumer should pickup one partitions and hence, 9 consumer should pick up documents from  9 partitions

but what happens is:
one consumer picks up messages from three paritions one of different topic.

**e.g. i have three topics Topic_A,Topic_B and Topic_C and three partitions each. hence parititions are as below:**

> Topic_A_0, Topic_A_1, Topic_A_2, Topic_B_0, Topic_B_1, Topic_B_2,
>   Topic_C_0, Topic_C_1, Topic_C_2

**When i create 9 consumers, 
the distribution works as below:**

```
Consumer1: Topic_A_0,Topic_B_0,Topic_C_0 
Consumer2: Topic_A_1,Topic_B_1,Topic_C_1 
Consumer3: Topic_A_2,Topic_B_2,Topic_C_2
Consumer4,Consumer5,Consumer6,Consumer7,Consumer8,Consumer9 are idle
```

**It should be**

```
Consumer1: Topic_A_0
Consumer2: Topic_A_1
Consumer3: Topic_A_2

Consumer4: Topic_B_0
Consumer5: Topic_B_1
Consumer6: Topic_B_2

Consumer7: Topic_C_0 
Consumer8: Topic_C_1 
Consumer9: Topic_C_2
```

**Is there any configuration i need to let all 9 consumer pick up messages from 9 unique parititons?**

Comment: Are all consumers subscribed to all three topics using the `subscribe()` API? Are you using the default partition assignment strategy or using something specific in the config?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your all your consumers are subscribing to same set of topics under the same consumer group id. For the list of topics, you can pass a predefined list or a regular expression for consumers to subscribe from. The consumer-id can be set using `group.id` property in consumer.

Answer (score 0):

The default partition assignment strategy doesn't work across topics so this is the expected behaviour. A similar question here : [Kafka Consumers are balanced across topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303022/kafka-consumers-are-balanced-across-topics)